# What are the strategic uses for God bridging?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-bedwars

When I play Hypixel bedwars, I rarely see God bridging. I'm not sure if that's because it's useless or costs too many blocks. **So, what are the strategic uses for God Bridging if there are any?**

---

For those who don't know what God bridging is:

*God bridging is a form of bridging without any shifting. You walk backward and spam place blocks at a certain angle.*
This is a video on how to God Bridge:

Comment: This is likely to attract only opinionated answers. If it could be reworded to something more around strategic uses for a "God bridge" it may be more suited. You should also explain what a God bridge is for those who don't know (such as myself).

Comment: ok @TimmyJim! I will do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one benefit I know.  It is ridiculously fast, probably the fastest method of bridging.  It's definitely not useless, but I think there are three reasons that most people don't use it.

1. It's really really hard to do.  It requires a high cps or really accurate timing and with both, it's easy to miss a block and die.
2. It's risky.  I'm not a high-level player, but I think a lot of high-level players have decided that its speed is not fast enough to justify how easy it can be to fall off vs the speed of ninja bridging.
3. It takes a while to start it.  I've only seen one person do it, so I could be wrong, but it took him a while to get started bridging because he had to aim at the right spot and get his trigger finger ready, which could make you vulnerable to an attack.

Like I said before, I'm not a very good bed wars player, this is just my observation.  Imho it's better to practice regular speed bridging (some call it ninja bridging).  Even Technoblade who is amazing at bed wars doesn't God bridge (at least to my knowledge)  and he seems to be doing fine.  =)

Comment: Note: Speed tellies are the fastest method of bridging. God bridging doesn't even come close to them in terms of speed. But yes, god bridging is pretty much useless if you can't do it consistently because it's not that much faster than speed bridging anyways. But if you can god bridge, you can probably do block extensions easily as well, which is a definite advantage because you can prevent yourself from falling off the map.